# AJAX Post missing variable

Tags: javascript, ajax

Im using an ajax call like so:

```
o.open("POST",q,true);
o.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
o.setRequestHeader("Content-length",p.length);
o.setRequestHeader("Connection","close");
```

Where q = the url and query string.
p = the query string only.

My query takes the form of: `"/apps/nettrax/f/events_detail.php?get=1&ids="+multiple values added like this: 123~34567~567~678~etc`

This all works if there are a few values, but large value strings fail - the variable **ids** does not pass (although **get** is passed)...
* Im not using jquery.

Comment: Where does it fail? Use something like Firebug or Charles Proxy to look at the requests being sent, and examine your server logs to look at the requests being received. Is the browser failing to send the data or is the server failing to accept it?

Comment: There is a limit to the length of a url. When you say large, how many characters are we talking?

Answer (score 2):

You're sending a POST request, but specifiying the parameters in GET via the URL. There's a limit on the size of URLs, so this won't work. You should be passing the parameters in the `send()` call, so that they are specified as POST data:

```
var parameters = "ids=" + encodeURIComponent(ids);
o.open("POST","events_detail.php",true);
o.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
o.setRequestHeader("Content-length",p.length);
o.setRequestHeader("Connection","close");
o.send(parameters);
```

Comment: didn't notice that, he's sending a post while passing parameters through get. nice

Answer (score 0):

I guess one this two things may be happening:

**a)** your url string is too long, so it's beeing truncated

**b)** your parameters are not encoded as the url needs to be, so the string "breaks" the url. if using php use a function like urlencode() or build your own one.